# When using CocoaPods and Swift Package Manager (SPM), is there a difference in the size of the archived app?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I want to reduce the app size in the App Store.
However, I would like to know if there is a difference in the size of the app when using CocoaPods and SPM.

Currently, the size of the app is more than 400 megabytes.

I have checked the resources of the app's images, but the total size of the resources is not large.

I suspect that the external libraries may be the problem.

Comment: the package manager won't make any difference to the size of the app; they just add the code to your project.  It would be unusual for compiled code to be the major contributor to your app's size.  Why don't you open the IPA file and take al look - It is just a zip file

Comment: @Paulw11 
I checked ipa and found that the file [projectname]-arm64.dbg.v is over 300 mega.
What is this?

Comment: Some sort of debug symbols file?  How are you building your app?